# How do I make something happen with the open button for a file input

Tags: html, css, file-upload

I gave a messaging website and I want to add a file sender thing so I put the input visibility to hidden and added a label, but now I don't want to have a submit button, how do I make the open button (when you select a file) act as a submit input?

```css
.addmessagebutton {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: url("../images/plus.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
        <label for="file" style="cursor: pointer; z-index: 1; position: fixed; bottom: 0;"><div class="addmessagebutton"></div>Example</label>
        <input  style="opacity: 0; position: fixed; z-index: 10; bottom: 0;" type="file" name="file" value="w">
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another button with an onclick action.
The action could be form.submit();

Answer (score 0):

You can call form's submit event on input change like so:

```
$('input[name=file]').change(function(e){
    $(this).parent().submit();
})
```